# Phpexcel crashes while creating pdf file with dompdf

Tags: php, phpexcel, dompdf

I want to save phpexcel document as pdf, but created file has lot's extra lines which shouldn't be here and also contents of file don't fit in page with portrait orientation. I tried to change orientation to landscape, but creation crashed with the following mistake: Frame not found in cellmap

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helps to hide extra lines:
$phpDoc->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setShowGridlines(false);

But I still don't know how to change doc orientation to landscape without crash